# Argocd ignores retry options: disabled

Tags: git, argocd

I have an ArgoCD (v 2.8.4) Application and from ArgoCD UI I see that the RETRY OPTIONS is "Retry disabled"

I have a Job with the following hook and the backoff limit set to 2

```
annotations:
   argocd.argoproj.io/hook: Sync
   argocd.argoproj.io/hook-delete-policy: BeforeHookCreation
```

If the Job fails I see that ArgoCd is ignoring the retry options and it continues to sync (deletes the job and redeploy it) for 10 minutes

I need ArgoCD to mark the Sync as failed as soon as the job fails, but it took more than 10 minutes to ArgoCD to stop synchronizing the current commit which was making the Job failing and start synchronizing the last commit with the fix.

In the image below, you can see that ArgoCD has already tried to Sync 5 times the application even if the Retry is disabled and there is new commit waiting to be sync (this second commit should fix the job issue)
[image]

Application:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I set in the Application yaml

```
retry: 
  limit: 1
  backoff:
    duration: 1s
    factor: 1
    maxDuration: 1m
```

Then ArgoCD retries 2 times and then it fails. Not perfect but better than waiting 10 minutes.

Comment: Is this somewhere documented? I could not find it in the documentation, only in GitHub issue you published.

https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/15624